# What's !* in the password field in /etc/shadow?

Tags: linux, password, arch-linux, shadow

Looking into my `/etc/shadow` file of a fairly new box today (running Arch), I see some passwords as `*` (disabled) but some others as `!*`, `!!` and as `!`. Presumably that means "disabled", too, but why is the value different?

Is there some convention that I haven't heard of? :-) and if so where would that be documented?

Excerpt:

```
root:*:14871::::::
dbus:!!:18407::::::
dnsmasq:!*:18499::::::
shepherd:!:18502:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252016/difference-between-vs-vs-in-etc-shadow

Comment: It would be nice to know just which tools implement those conventions. useradd, maybe? Also, what about `!*`?

Answer (score 3):

Synthesizing the [Unix & Linux page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252016/difference-between-vs-vs-in-etc-shadow) regarding the `/etc/shadow` file

- `*`: "By convention, accounts that are not intended to be logged in to (e.g. bin, daemon, sshd) only contain a single asterisk in the password field"
- `!`: Both "!" and "!!" being present in the password field mean an account is locked.
- `!!`: But "!!" in an account entry in shadow means the account of an user has been created, but not yet given a password

The strings `*`, `!` and `!!` all effectively make that the user cannot login (since an encrypted password will never be 1 or 2 characters).

Comment: This isn't just a length restriction. Even if the original hash is present, adding either `*` or `!` will render them unmatchable, since neither character appears in a valid hash for all hash types commonly used in `/etc/shadow`. In this way, a user's "previous" password can be preserved, and removing the `*` or `!` can return it to service.